# Many Rewrite Parameters/Rules

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, urls

I have a bible page which is page_id of 135 and I am trying to create multiple WordPress rewrite rules. I am trying to obtain something like either of the following:

- website/bible/nasb
- website/bible/nasb/Genesis
- website/bible/nasb/Genesis/1

I want to be able to access the query parameters via WordPress's get_query_var() function. However, all of the parameters seem to be kept in get_query_var('version'). They won't split into 3 different parameters. It puts "nasb/Genesis/1" into the version parameter.

I want to be able to access the parameters like this:

- get_query_var('version')
- get_query_var('book')
- get_query_var('chapter')

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'init' , function() {

add_rewrite_tag('%version%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%book%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%chapter%','([^&]+)');

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^bible/(.+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=135&version=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^bible/(.+)/(.+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=135&version=$matches[1]&book=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^bible/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=135&version=$matches[1]&book=$matches[2]&chapter=$matches[3]',
    'top'
);  

flush_rewrite_rules();

} );
```

Thank you.

P.S.

I currently have my permalinks set to post name which cleans up the url, so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `(.+)` matches any character, *including the slash*, so any combo of parameters will always match your first rule, with anything that follows being passed as the version query var. Change all instances of `(.+)` to `([^/]+)` to match all characters except the slash.

Comment: Thank you. I am not good at regexes at all. It works perfectly in combination with TheDeadMedic's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want rewrite tags - these are only useful for defining permalink structures. Instead, keep your rules and [add the parameters as query vars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars):

```
function wpse_205120_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'version';
    $qvars[] = 'chapter';
    $qvars[] = 'bible';
    return $qvars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_205120_query_vars_query_vars' );
```

You'll also want [to get rid of that `flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage) once it's all working.